# Django Rest Framework, returns 405 on POST

Tags: python, angularjs, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

After upgrading from DRF v3.0 to v3.3.2, i'm getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) when trying to create a model using POST Method.

and i can't catch the request on the debugger to figure out where it goes wrong.

my DRF settings in Project/settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGINATE_BY'             : 10
}
```

my urlpatterns in project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/v1/seeds/', include('seed.urls')),
    ...
    url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

my urlpatterns  in project/seed/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from seed.views import SeedViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'^', SeedViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

my project/seed/views.py

```
from seed.serializers import SeedSerializer
from seed.models import Seed
from rest_framework import viewsets

class SeedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Seed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SeedSerializer
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return super(SeedViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

my project/seed/serializer.py

```
from authentication.serializers import AccountSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from seed.models import Seed


class SeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = AccountSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Seed
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'jobs', 'list_name', 'proxyType', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user', 'jobs', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

what could i have done wrong ?
or is it something i should do diferently because of the upgrade ?

**edit**
and i'm using angularJs to Post to the API, and here is my function inside my service:

```
function create(list_name, proxyType) {
    return $http.post('/api/v1/seeds/', {
    list_name: list_name,
    proxyType: proxyType
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate the error with a failing python `rest_framework` test?  If so, can you add the failing test code to the question, so it is more clear what is going on.

Comment: For me it seems, that you should have a `create` method instead of `perform_create` as `create` belongs to [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and `perform_create` belongs to [GenericAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) but that's just a guess

Comment: @AaronLelevier, can you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed SeedViewSet from `viewsets.ModelViewSet` to `generics.ListCreateAPIView`, then i overrided the `post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
```

Please use the below for the post .

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
def perform_create(self, request):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return super(SeedViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```